# Non-static field mFirebaseAnalytics can not be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-analytics, buildbox

I am using Buildbox. I defined a custom openURL method in Buildbox. I am trying to track worlds with events. How can I reach non-static mFirebaseAnalytics instance in static method?

```
package com.secrethq.utils;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;

import com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics;

import android.app.Activity;


public class PTServicesBridge extends Activity
    implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    }


    public static void openUrl( String url ){
        Log.v(TAG, "PTServicesBridge  -- Open URL " + url);

        PTServicesBridge.urlString = url;

        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("levelname", url);
        mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("levels", params); //Problematic line it gives error.



    }


}
```

**Problematic line:**

```
 mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("levels", params); //Problematic line it gives error.
```

Comment: you can not access non-static variable from a static method. remove static keyword from openUrl method.

Comment: if I remove this method is not working anyway I should access it.

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: Code does not enter here:

Log.v(TAG, "PTServicesBridge  -- Open URL " + url);

Not working these lines. It works if only I make it static

Comment: Are you accessing openUrl method from other class?

Comment: Buildbox trigger this method when user click open URL button in the game. So I do not access, buildbox access and run it.

If I remove static from this method, buildbox never trigger it button not working. If I make it static so no problem, method is triggered.

Comment: @gurkanstack, there must be something you're missing here. Apps such as this generally highly discourage using `static` keyword in general. The right solution **is** to remove the `static`, and then figure out why buildox can't find your method (most likely you aren't referencing it correctly, but I can't see your screen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just dig up the buildbox code, Here is how you can achieve your task!

Use PTServicesBridge.s_activity to get FirebaseAnalytics instance inside the method.

```
public static void openUrl( String url ){
        Log.v(TAG, "PTServicesBridge  -- Open URL " + url);

        PTServicesBridge.urlString = url;

        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("levelname", url);

        // Get FirebaseAnalytics Object
        FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(PTServicesBridge.activity);
        mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("levels", params); //Problematic line it gives error.
}
```

Comment: @gurkanstack there must be something which gives you an activity object inside PTServicesBridge. Do check!

Comment: I just took reference from this link: http://ezelia.com/2016/buildbox-hook-android-ios

Comment: You are wonderful! I solved it by changing to 

FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(activity);